# Looking to combine my ride and crash into one main crash/ride

Tags: drum-kits, rock-n-roll, crash-cymbal, ride-cymbal

Currently, I use a 21inch Paiste alpha mega bell ride and an 18inch Zildjian K medium Thin crash. I don't really use the ride except for maybe one song we play, and am looking to consolidate the crash and ride into one that I could use as my main crash for all songs, but still could pass as a ride when needed on the rare occasion I do, for setup's sake. I play heavy rock music.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Hi Vanny. Welcome to the site. There are a fair number of drummers here, so try posting this question in [The Practice Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room). Equipment recommendations like this are off-topic on the main site.

Comment: Many cymbal makers make and sell crash/ride cymbals. Depending on how you strike them they serve both purposes. They usually range from 18-22” and are medium weight. You just have to go to a music store that sells cymbals, try some out and see if you find one that suits you.